# cant access JSON response in callback AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my net tab I am seeing the responses coming back but I can't get access to the data for some reason.

Here is the direct link: https://github.com/users/gigablox/contributions_calendar_data

*Using Angular 1.2 rc2. Tried a couple different ways...*

**$http**

```
var url = "https://github.com/users/gigablox/contributions_calendar_data?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
$http.jsonp(url).success(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

**$resource**

```
var handle = $resource('https://github.com/users/gigablox/contributions_calendar_data',{},{
  get:{
    method:'JSONP',
    isArray: false, //response is wrapped as an array. tried true and false
    params:{callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'}
  }
});

handle.get().$promise.then(
function(data){
    console.log(data);
}).
function(error){
    console.log(error); //undefined but 200 OK on response?
});
```

Comment: Use debugging.. put a breakpoint on the success line in both cases and look at the variables to see what they hold.  Then tells us what you see

Comment: is the callback firing?

Comment: @Jason In the `$resource` error callback it's returning the data property as undefined... But the response in my net tab is 200 OK. What is strange is the `angular.callbacks._0()` function isn't wrapping the response. The response type is an array as you will see in that direct link, so I've tried falgging `isArray:true`. No dice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are requesting a flat file, so the server isn't wrapping the data in the javascript function call specified by the `jsonp_callback` querystring parameter.  Further CORS is preventing you from fetching the file directly using $http/xhr.

In general, if you use $http.jsonp the specified callback function needs to reside in the global scope, and then you need to 're-angularify' the response data.

Here's an example using the wordpress api: http://jsfiddle.net/Rjfre/23/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" id='ctl'>
  <h2 ng-show="data">Data from callback</h2>
  <pre>{{data}}</pre>

  <h2 ng-show="success">Success</h2>
  <pre>{{success}}</pre>

  <h2 ng-hide="data">Error</h2>
  <pre>{{error}}</pre>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
var url = "http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/wtmpeachtest.wordpress.com/posts?callback=jsonp_callback";

$http.jsonp(url).then(
        function(s) { $scope.success = JSON.stringify(s); }, 
        function(e) { $scope.error = JSON.stringify(e); } );
}

function jsonp_callback(data) {
    var el = document.getElementById('ctl');
    var scope = angular.element(el).scope();
    scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.data = JSON.stringify(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jason for your response. I have forked your fiddle and swapped out the wordpress URL out for my own but am still running into the same issue: http://jsfiddle.net/NUaxn/

Comment: yes, as I said, you can't use the data from that github page.  it's a flat page, it won't get wrapped in a javascript callback.

Comment: Oh I see. So this is impossible to do in the confines of the framework?

Comment: This is a github thing, github is returning the file with a content-type of application/json, but it's not wrapping the returned data in a function call. Here is more information about JSONP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: I see, their servers arent supporting JSONP or CORS for that particular resource. Thank you!

Comment: Could you use this for oauth?

Comment: @Jason, what would be an alternative to for something that does not support JSONP or CORS? I am having the same issue with something else

Comment: @Vnge you setup a proxy server to call the raw data and then wrap it yourself before passing it back to the browser. although if you proxy the call from your server its just as relevent to use a straight ajax call to your server vs using jsonp.