# Angular.js reading External JSON Address

Tags: json, angularjs

Hey guys I am trying to use an EPA API that provides daily UV Index information in JSON.

The link I am trying to read at the moment is:

```
http://iaspub.epa.gov/enviro/efservice/getEnvirofactsUVHOURLY/ZIP/33126/JSON?callback=callBackFn
```

If you open that link it shows valid JSON, but when I use it in my Angular.js code it does not read it, and my variable stays as unknown. My code is:

```
var tanApp = angular.module('tanApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.awesomeThings = [
  'HTML5 Boilerplate',
  'AngularJS',
  'Karma'
];
$scope.data = 'unknown';
    $http.get('http://iaspub.epa.gov/enviro/efservice/getEnvirofactsUVHOURLY/ZIP/33126/JSON?callback=callBackFn').success(function(data){
        $scope.data = data;
});
    tanApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }]);
```

My HTML code is {{data}}.

When I take out the "JSON" portion, it comes up as XML, since it is the default, and that is actually showing up, but I need it as JSON.

Can someone possibly get this to work or provide some help? I can offer bitcoin as a bounty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the URI you're using returns raw JSON instead of JSONP. You can either setup a server-side proxy or check with your API provider to see if there's a way to get a valid JSONP response.

If you can get valid JSONP, you will also have to setup a callback to handle the response.

In that case, reference the accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807901/cant-access-json-response-in-callback-angularjs).

Comment: So there is nothing I can do with the raw JSON? The API is a RESTful Data Service API, does that change anything?

Comment: I don't see any way to get a JSONP response from their servers, and their JSON response is not returned with the necessary headers for CORS. So, it appears that your only option is to setup a proxy, either on the same domain your app is hosted on or another server that will provide you with the necessary CORS headers or valid JSONP.

Comment: I really appreciate it marck, can you point me to a resource where I can learn more about setting up this proxy?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967209/cant-read-json-response-from-server/13967260#13967260) including the caveat. You may want to contact the service provider and see if they can suggest the best approach that would fit their guidelines.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I will likely contact them and see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this using `$http.jsonp()` instead of `$http.get()`. Also if your using `$http.jsonp()` then the callback should be set to `"JSON_CALLBACK"`.

e.g.

```
$http.jsonp('http://iaspub.epa.gov/enviro/efservice/getEnvirofactsUVHOURLY/ZIP/33126/JSON?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.data = data;
    }
```

Comment: Still getting unknown. Not sure if maybe I have to sign up for API access?